# Smoothing matrix for visual representation

Tags: matrix, r, geospatial, signal-processing, data-visualization

I recently started playing around with R and am currently trying to plot GPS data points onto a perspective plot. I have a script that works and I get my desired results out of it and it works ok for my test file of about 12000 data points, but when I increase the amount of data points to about 4 million it takes a while to complete, but still works.

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of complete the following code specifically the part where I call smoothing, based on my rough calculations, the script has to make about 2.64 billion calculations, depending on how many times I want to run the "smoother" over it. My little laptop currently takes a few hours to run this script on my large data set.

```
#get file

input <- read.csv("c:/Users/Travis/Documents/newPath.csv", header=F, sep=",")

#convert inputs to integers
input[1] <- abs(input[1])*100000
input[2] <- abs(input[2])*100000

#find lat/lon min
latMin <- min(input[1])
lonMin <- min(input[2])
altMin <- min(input[3])
#turn columns into arbitrary numbers that R can use
input[1] <- input[1] - (latMin - 1)
input[2] <- input[2] - (lonMin - 1)

#find lat/lon max 
latMax <- max(input[1])
lonMax <- max(input[2])
altMin <- min(input[3])
altMean <- mean(input[,3])
#make storage matrix
store <- matrix(NA, length(input[,1]), 3)

#make plotting matrix -- filled with NA could be filled with mean, min or median

plotMat <- matrix(altMin, latMax, lonMax)

#fill storage matrix

store[,1] <- input[,1]
store[,2] <- input[,2]
store[,3] <- input[,3]

#loop through rows of storage and plot in plot matrix
for (i in 1:length(store[,1])) {
t <- store[i,]
lat <- t[1]
lon <- t[2]
alt <- t[3]
plotMat[lat,lon] <- alt
}




#smooth start from top left and work down to the right
smoothTimes <- 330
t <- 1
                    #My smoother goes here

while (t <= smoothTimes) {
i <- 1
j <- 1
smoother  <- 4
# re-add original values
for (k in 1:length(store[,1])) {
l <- store[k,]
lat <- l[1]
lon <- l[2]
alt <- l[3]
plotMat[lat,lon] <- alt

}
while (j+smoother < length(plotMat[,1])) {
    newVal <- mean(plotMat[j:(j+smoother),i:(i+smoother)])
    plotMat[j:(j+smoother),i:(i+smoother)] <- newVal
    i <- i + (smoother-1)
        if (i+smoother > length(plotMat[1,])) {
            i <- 1
            j <- j + (smoother-1)
        }
}  

#smooth start from bottom right and work left and up

i <- length(plotMat[1,]) - smoother
j <- length(plotMat[,1]) - smoother


while (j+smoother < length(plotMat[,1])) {
    newVal <- mean(plotMat[j:(j+smoother),i:(i+smoother)])
    plotMat[j:(j+smoother),i:(i+smoother)] <- newVal
    i <- i - (smoother-1)
        if (i < smoother) {
            i <- length(plotMat[1,]) - smoother
            j <- j - (smoother-1)
        }
}

t <- t +1
}           

                #second iteration without adding originals

                smoothTimes <- 2
                t <- 1


                while (t <= smoothTimes) {
                    i <- 1
                    j <- 1
                    smoother  <- 2


                    while (j+smoother < length(plotMat[,1])) {
                        newVal <- mean(plotMat[j:(j+smoother),i:(i+smoother)])
                        plotMat[j:(j+smoother),i:(i+smoother)] <- newVal
                        i <- i + (smoother-1)
                            if (i+smoother > length(plotMat[1,])) {
                                i <- 1
                                j <- j + (smoother-1)
                            }
                    }  

                    #smooth start from bottom right and work left and up

                    i <- length(plotMat[1,]) - smoother
                    j <- length(plotMat[,1]) - smoother


                    while (j+smoother < length(plotMat[,1])) {
                        newVal <- mean(plotMat[j:(j+smoother),i:(i+smoother)])
                        plotMat[j:(j+smoother),i:(i+smoother)] <- newVal
                        i <- i - (smoother-1)
                            if (i < smoother) {
                                i <- length(plotMat[1,]) - smoother
                                j <- j - (smoother-1)
                            }
                    }

                    t <- t +1
                }                   


sideH <- altMin
 plotMat[1,] <- sideH
 plotMat[,1] <- sideH
 plotMat[length(plotMat[,1]),] <- sideH
 plotMat[,length(plotMat[1,])] <- sideH
par(bg = "black")   
#png(filename="temp.png", width=500, height=500)
persp(plotMat, expand=0.2, theta=30, phi=30, box=F, border=NA, col="green2", shade="0.25")
#dev.off()
```

Here is a sample of what the data looks like coming in:

33.46681,-82.30175,104.0

33.46681,-82.30175,104.0

33.46685,-82.30221,143.0

33.46683,-82.30217,145.0

33.46685,-82.30197,121.0

33.46685,-82.30196,119.0

Comment: Or if anyone could give me a more efficient methodology of going about it that would be great too. The last model that I'm trying to make is already 24 hours in and still not done

Comment: How about some example input?  Have you also looked at existing libraries, because if you can find one with an optimised algorithm and/or an underlying C part it would speed things up significantly.  In general it would be better to use vectorised operations and no/less loops if possible.

Comment: @ferada I have added some a sample of what the data looks like coming in. As far as the libraries go, I have looked at a few, but didn't see anything that seemed to fit was I was trying to do, this is most like due to the fact that I am new to R and don't quite understand all of what I am looking at yet